# how to create bootstrap modal with transparent background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the modal, it shows black background instead of transparent. 
It might be a problem related to the CSS.
Note:  I changed Opacity:.7 in the class .fade but that didn't affect anything

```
  <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal"  style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:800px;width:600px; background:none; " role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Adding Wall</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label>Wall Id:     </label><input type="text" id="wallNametxt"/><br>
         <label>Wall Name:</label><input type="text" id="wallNametxt1"/>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="button" id="btn" value="Add!" name="save" class="btn btn-default"/>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div><!--End of Modal-->
```

**[Click to see the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d20Sn.png)**

Update!!
It worked perfectly. But the modal is being placed in a glass box with the same height of the page.
 I can limit that to the height, width properties, but I would prefer to know the reason.
[Click to see output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT2c3.png)

Comment: it works fine , whats your browser ?

Comment: Provide proper code, if possible create working snippet.

Comment: MS Edge, Google Chrome

Comment: @Fatima transparent? Do you mean when the modal appear, you can still see whats behind it?

Comment: @Fatima i think i have found why , can u please confirm ?

Comment: I tried the code on a separate page it works fine, but when I integrate it with the whole project, that contains bootstrap.css, bootstrap.min.css files v3.3.6, the modal is not workin properly.

Comment: There is a big possibility that your problem is related on css. Why do you need to load bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css? You don't need both, and you can just simply use one of it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As I can see Bootstrap have the class `.modal-backdrop` and they are setting the background color to black, you can overwrite this with this code:

```
.modal-backdrop {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0001) !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
That worked perfectly, but I still have borders or glass box surrounding the modal. I can limit that with height and width but I want to know why and fix it from there

Answer (score 4):

if you are using Bootstrap 4, you could just set the attribute "data-backdrop" in the HTML of the "open modal" button to "false". 
e.g. `<button data-backdrop="false">Open modal</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Hey You need to override the bootstrap css with this code. I you try to add style property without important keyword the style not work replace your code with this.

```
modal-backdrop {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by overriding the following classes in my component CSS. In brief, I changed the background to transparent and removed borders.

```
.modal-content {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: 0px !important
}

.modal-header {
    border: 0px !important
}
```

Complete implementation available here:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-bootstrap-playground-forked-hrz6x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

```
.modal { 
    --bs-modal-bg: #00000000 !important; 
}
```

for Bootstrap 5